# How to install Tomee in AWS ubuntu environment?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, apache-tomee

I want to install tomee on ubuntu AWS. I have installed JDK and its working fine with maven 3 is working and my Java -version give correct jdk details.

I can start the tomee with

```
sudo ./startup
```

but I can't see any output on myserver.public.ip:8080

I get page can not found error

Comment: http://tomee.apache.org/refcard/refcard.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have port 8080 open in your security group. Open the AWS Web Console, go to EC2, Security Groups and edit the security group that your instance is running in (probably the default one?). After adding port 8080 on TCP for all hosts (0.0.0.0:8080) you should be able to access the output. Also, sometime it takes about 5 minutes for the Sec Group changes to propagate.

If this doesn't work, you should test out that tomee is running correctly by connecting to it locally (such as curl localhost:8080). If the output is not correct, check your tomee config.

Comment: I can see the output of curl localhost:8080, it show Apache tomcat page details

Also I have below Security settings
Ports Protocol Source launch-wizard-5

22 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
80 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔
8080 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 ✔

Comment: you're using the elastic IP attached to the server to access it? like http://52.52.21.11:8080?